# Simple set theory: $A\cap (B\cup C) \subset (A \cap B) \cup C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If each of $A, B, C$ are sets then $A\cap (B\cup C) \subset (A \cap B) \cup C.$

Proof:  Let $A, B, C$ be sets.  Suppose $x \in A \cap (B \cup C).$
Then $x \in A $ and $ x \in B \cup C.$

$x \in A$ & either $x \in B$ or $x \in C.$

Thus we have 2 cases:

**Case 1:** $x \in A$ & $x \in B$

Then $x \in A \cap B$, $x \in A \cap B$ or $x \in C.$

$x \in (A \cap B) \cup C.$

**Case 2:** $x \in A$ & $x \in C.$

$ x \in (A \cap B) \cup C.$

In either case $ A \cap (B \cup C) \subset (A \cap B) \cup C.$

We went over this example in class and I'm just confused about Case 2.  How does $x \in A$ & $x \in C$ give you that $ x \in (A \cap B) \cup C.$

Comment: $C$ is a subset of $(A\cap B)\cup C$, so $x\in C$ implies that $x\in (A\cap B)\cup C$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 2:**

**Hint:** observe that $ C\subseteq(A \cap B) \cup C$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cap$ and $\cup$ are distributive over each other we have $A\cap (B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup  (A\cap C)\subset (A\cap B)\cup C.$